# Crossed X logo with outlines

Tags: logo, branding

I'm making a logo with a centered X and I know I've already seen a logo that looks like this
[image]
 I would say in an english clothing brand.

I would really appreciate it if any of you could help me finding the original.

Comment: Hi @C00ky, quiz question are off-topic here

Comment: Google "apparel crossed arrows logo" and you will find lots of similar images.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that looks very similar to the firefighter logo/badge used at various fire stations across the country. Also looks like catholic school and prestigious colleges and private school badges as well [image: Firefighter badge of courage logo design] Those were my first thoughts when I saw your drawing. Just do a search for firefighter badges or crests or private school crests college crest etc... - www.extremeflyerdesigns.com